# How to send an object and authenticate with passport at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, saml-2.0

As vague as the question seems, I need a way to send a json object and also authenticate with passport at the same time. The object is req.isAuthenticated which will be picked up with axios later in the frontend as a checkpoint. That's what I intend. So far with the code below, the object will not be sent.

```html
app.get('/login',
    passport.authenticate('saml', {
        successRedirect: '/assert',
        failureRedirect: '/',
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.json({isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated()})
    }
);
```

Comment: send it where??

Comment: to http://myaddress/login, the same /login as for authentication

Comment: so it should go to myaddress/login with the isAuthetiicated object?

Comment: yes, it. should be sent there

Comment: please have a look, hope it helps

Comment: vote up, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example sample from my project:

```
authorizeLocal: (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local-auth', (err, user, info) => {
      if (info) console.log(info);
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!user) return res.status(200).send({failReason: 'wrong login/password'});
      req.logIn(user, err => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        delete user.password;
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 hours
        if (user.role === 'operator') {
          user.status = 'Online';
          operatorsService.setStatus('Online', user.id)
            .then(result => {
              dialogsService.getWaitingDialogs();
              user.work_time = result;
              res.status(200).send(user);
           })
           .catch(() => res.status(200).send({failReason: 'Service error'}));
        } else res.status(200).send(user);
      });
    })(req, res, next);
},
```

There you can see passport `req.logIn`, which (needs `local-auth` strategy or tother in your case) performs auth and if success fires callback logic. Deeper you can have any user/object get/generation logic. I left my case for example. `OperatorsService.setStatus` returns some time data, which is stored to user (user is got as callback param after strategy logic run) end sent as response. You can add `user.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();` there.

So you'll have smth like:

**auth.route.js**

```
app.get('/login', authCtrl.authorizeLocal);
```

**authCtrl.js**

```
authorizeLocal: (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('saml', (err, user, info) => {
      if (info) console.log(info);
      if (err) return next(err);
      // if (!user) return res.status(200).send({failReason: 'wrong login/password'});
      req.logIn(user, err => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.status(200).send({isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated()}));
      });
    })(req, res, next);
},
```